# Ubuntu setup HP 7520 wireless?

Tags: 12.10

I am setting up a wireless printer HP7520 to .
My problem is HP7520 is  not working wireless with .
He still need the USB connection.
I have don the configuration many times..it still not works
So I have connected the usb cabel and it works....but not wireless..

What Im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

This printer works with Ubuntu 12 if you upgrade to HPLIP 3.12.2

Run 'dpkg -l hplip' to see your current version

See this page on how to upgrade:
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.